# Yet another "inconsistent reputation history"

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

I found something in my reputation history that I cannot explain. Could someone please put some light on this?

[image: 25 + 10 = 26]

According to this log, 25+10=36

Comment: That question was already closed 2012 with the same dupe and you realize that know?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try checking the "show removed posts" checkbox.

> [image]

That "invisible" +1 rep is almost certainly the result of a post you downvoted being removed.

Comment: yep, that was it. Thanks.

Comment: Has this question not been granted FAQ status yet? Something that explains generally how and why to use the "show removed posts" checkbox?

Comment: @TheEstablishment Iunno. Not that I'm aware of. Personally, I don't get why the preference even exists in the first place. Seems like a no-brainer to enable this as soon as you notice it.

Comment: @lunboks it is not that easy to notice... maybe the position should be changed to the top of the list instead of the bottom.Currently if I do not scroll all the way down I cannot see the checkbox.